# Server Side Array Response Correct but Empty Array Returned from Fetch Request on Client Side

Tags: node.js, express, fetch

I have a server side js file that runs the following function. This queries a mysql database based on the selection of a drop down input on an html form and then submitting this selected item.

**Server Side JS**

```
exports.findTreatment = (req, res) => {
  const selectedTreatment = req.body.selectedTreatment;

  console.log(selectedTreatment);

  db.query('SELECT * FROM treatments WHERE treatmentName = ?', [selectedTreatment], (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error
    }
    console.log(result);
    return res.json(result);

  });
};
```

This works fine and console logs the json object related to the selected treatment as expected however, when I try to call this with a fetch request from the client side I get an empty array back.

**Client Side JS**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const form = document.getElementById('searchTreatment');

  if (form) {
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      const formData = new FormData(form);
      console.log('FormData', formData);
      console.log('Selected Treatment:', formData.get('selectedTreatment'));

      fetch('manager/findTreatment', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
      })

      .then ((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        if(response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        } else {
          throw new Error('Form submission failed');
        }
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      
        if (data && data.length > 0) {
          const selectedTreatment = data[0];
          document.getElementById('treatmentNameUpdate').value = selectedTreatment.treatmentName;
          document.getElementById('treatmentPriceUpdate').value = selectedTreatment.treatmentPrice;
          document.getElementById('treatmentDurationUpdate').value = selectedTreatment.treatmentDuration;
          document.getElementById('costOfTreatmentUpdate').value = selectedTreatment.costOfTreatment;
        } else {
          console.error('No treatment found.');
        }
        })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    });
  }
});
```

**Console Logs**

FormData FormData {}                                         clientside.js:153
Selected Treatment: 1 Treamtent                              clientside.js:161
Response {type: 'basic', url: 'http://localhost:3000/manager/findTreatment', redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}                                            clientside.js:169
[]                                                           clientside.js:178

I have reviewed other questions on the forum but have not been able to adapt the answers to fix my issue.

I have tried changing the client side code to an async await function but still get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) here:

```js
const formData = new FormData(form);
fetch('manager/findTreatment', {
   method: 'POST',
   body: formData,
})
```

That means the data is sent with encoding type `"multipart/form-data"`. In Express you would need to use a package that can parse that data such as [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer). However, you don't seem to be sending any file uploads so I would recommend you don't send `FormData` and just convert that data to JSON and so long as you are using the `app.use(express.json());` middleware on your server to parse the data you should be able to get the response you want.

Make these changes:

```js
const formData = new FormData(form);
console.log('FormData', formData);
console.log('Selected Treatment:', formData.get('selectedTreatment'));

const pojoForm = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries()); //< Convert to POJO

fetch('manager/findTreatment', {
   method: 'POST',
   body: JSON.stringify(pojoForm), //< Send as JSON
   headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json", //< Set correct header
   }
})
//...
//...
```

Comment: Thanks JQueeny, appreciate you taking the time to respond.

The form does include a possible file upload (not required) and I have Multer set up to deal with this.

I changed the formData variable from FormData to URLSearchParams whilst keeping the rest of the code the same and this worked for updating the data in the server although I must confess I dont understand the logic behind this. I also don't get file uploads updating from the form but I guess thats because I'm not dealing with this part of the form in my clientside code (its set up in the server endpoint).

Comment: @StephenCummings changing from FormData to URLSearchParams would have sent the data as `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` which is the default for forms. So long as you have a body parser on the server e.g `app.use(express.urlencoded())` then that's how the data was successfully parsed. You fixed it on your own.